Visible round bump on the ceiling near the gutter (second floor)
Just noticed this visible round bump on the outside ceiling of my roof near the gutter. I am not sure if this is a sign of leak or if that is already there ever since. House is essentially new built and purchased this year. Any thoughts?

it could be just trapped air bubble

If this was inside on a drywall wall, would almost think of a nail pop.

is it worth checking with a tradie? builder wont respond :(

What material is the soffit?  I think I can see smaller bumps in the corner as well.

What material are your eaves made of?

no idea tbh..bought this already built almost a year ago.
